# Position window to the bottom right of the window?

Tags: tidesdk

How do I Position window to the bottom right of the window? I was thinking getting the max width and max height of the user's screen then subtracting a few pixels but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the screen size (`window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`) and the window size to calculate the wanted position of the top left corner of the window, and then place it there:

```js
var app_window=Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow();
app_window.setX(window.screen.width-app_window.getWidth());
app_window.setY(window.screen.height-app_window.getHeight());
```